# Which is current / legacy: <soapenv:Envelope> or <soap:Envelope>

Tags: soap, soap-client, temenos-quantum

I have to tool to generate soap requests and it can do so in two ways. Either generating the request beginning with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://…" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

or with:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://…" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

I suspect that one is the current technique and the other is the legacy technique. But since only one has something resembling a date in the url I can't figure out which is.

Which of the two it the current version to be used for new requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [SOAP1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) is Older.

It uses namespace as `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`.

2. [SOAP1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/) is latest.

It uses namespace as `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`.

Refer links for more details.

> Which one should be used for new services?

SOAP1.2 should be used for new services as its latest and greatest, more cleaner and robust. Though now a days trend is more for Restfull Services then SOAP.

Comment: How to maintain the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) 1.1 version in Spring Boot SOAP project ?

Comment: How to set SOAP version?